# Почему создается новый Handler?

Tags: java, android

Почему во втором классе мы создаем два `Handler`: `mResponseHandler` и `mRequestHandler`? Почему нужно создать `mResponseHandler` в `onCreate` и затем передать в конструктор `mThumbnailDownloader`? Т.е почему в методе `hanldeRequest` мы вызывает `Runnablе` и там уже вызываем метод слушателя? Почему это нельзя сделать в `mRequestHandler`?

Есть такой код:

```java
public class PhotoGalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "PhotoGalleryFragment";
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private List<GalleryItem> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ThumbnailDownloader<PhotoHolder> mThumbnailDownloader;

    public static PhotoGalleryFragment newInstance() {
        return new PhotoGalleryFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        new FetchItemsTask().execute();

        Handler responseHandler = new Handler();

        mThumbnailDownloader = new ThumbnailDownloader<>(responseHandler);
        mThumbnailDownloader.setThumbnailDownloadListener(new ThumbnailDownloader.ThumbnailDownloadListener<PhotoHolder>() {
            @Override
            public void onThumbnailDownloaded(PhotoHolder target, Bitmap thumbnail) {
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), thumbnail);
                target.bindDrawable(drawable);
            }
        });
        mThumbnailDownloader.start();
        mThumbnailDownloader.getLooper();
        Log.i(TAG, "Background thread started");
    }
}
```

И есть второй класс:

```java
public class ThumbnailDownloader<T> extends HandlerThread {

    private static final String TAG = "ThumbnailDownloader";
    private static final int MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD = 0;

    private Handler mRequestHandler;
    private Handler mResponseHandler;
    private ConcurrentMap<T, String> mRequestMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private boolean mHasQuit = false;
    private ThumbnailDownloadListener<T> mThumbnailDownloadListener;
    public interface ThumbnailDownloadListener<T>{
        void onThumbnailDownloaded(T target, Bitmap thumbnail);
    }

    public void setThumbnailDownloadListener(ThumbnailDownloadListener<T> listener) {
        mThumbnailDownloadListener = listener;
    }

    public ThumbnailDownloader(Handler responseHandler) {
        super(TAG);
        mResponseHandler = responseHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLooperPrepared() {
        mRequestHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
                if(msg.what == MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD){
                    T target = (T)msg.obj;
                    Log.i(TAG, "Got a request for url " + mRequestMap.get(target));
                    handleRequest(target);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void handleRequest(final T target) {
        try {
            final String url = mRequestMap.get(target);
            if (url == null)
                return;

            byte[] bitmapBytes = new FlickrFetchr().getUrlBytes(url);
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapBytes.length);
            Log.i(TAG, "Bitmap created");

            mResponseHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(mRequestMap.get(target) != url || mHasQuit)
                        return;

                    mRequestMap.remove(target);
                    mThumbnailDownloadListener.onThumbnailDownloaded(target, bitmap);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.i(TAG, "Error downloading image");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Android сетевые операции обязаны выполняться в фоновом потоке, а операции с UI в главном.   Поэтому создаётся два `Handler` для обмена данными между потоками: `mResponseHandler` в главном, `mRequestHandler` в фоновом.
То есть вызывая метод слушателя в `Runnablе` заброшенном в `mResponseHandler` вы переводите его выполнение из фонового потока в главный.

Comment: А что будет, если я вызову метод слушателя просто из mRequestHandler, НЕ mResponseHandler.

Comment: Насколько я понял, в реализации слушателя картинка вставляется во вью элемента списка - так вот, на этом месте приложение упадёт с ошибкой, поскольку из фонового потока менять UI запрещено.

Comment: Понял спасибо !!!